# What is the most elegant way in Ruby to substitute '?' in string with values in array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have the following variables:

```
query = "(first_name = ?) AND (country = ?)" # string
values = ['Bob', 'USA'] # array
```

I need the following result:

```
result = "(first_name = Bob) AND (country = USA)" # string
```

The number of substitutions varies (1..20).

What is the best way to do it in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind destroying the array:

`query.gsub('?') { values.shift }`

Otherwise just copy the array and then do the replacements.

**Edited:** Used gsub('?') instead of a regex.

Comment: The solution I did is: query.gsub(/\?/).each_with_index {|_, i| values[i]} , but yours one looks more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a regex for a fixed string.

Comment: If you don't want to destroy `values`, you could call `#dup`. This is (a part of) [what Rails does internally](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0a71c7b/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L125).

Answer (score 3):

If you can control the `query` string, the [String#%](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-25) operator is what you need:

```
query = "(first_name = %s) AND (country = %s)" # string
values = ['Bob', 'USA'] # array
result = query % values
#=> "(first_name = Bob) AND (country = USA)"
```

You have to replace `?` with `%s` in your `query` string.

Comment: The query I got as a given, and I want to avoid additional replace. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
query = "(first_name = ?) AND (country = ?)"
values = ['Bob', 'USA']
result = query.dup
values.each{|s| result.sub!("?",s) }
p query
# >> "(first_name = Bob) AND (country = USA)"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
values.inject(query){|s1, s2| s1.sub("?", s2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), you could (should) use [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) with [*Array Conditions*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions).

This will raise [`ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/PreparedStatementInvalid.html) if you provide the wrong number of bind variables in `values`, which saves you from checking this yourself.

Not only is this elegant because Rails performs the substitutions for you, it will also help guard you against [SQL injection attacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection) by sanitising your SQL in the process.

#### Example

Assuming your model is called `User` and `query` and `value` are as in your question, this:

```
User.where(query, *values)
```

...would generate SQL like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name = 'Bob' AND country = 'USA';
```

#### Display only

The example above will execute the query. To display the generated SQL without execution, simply invoke [`ActiveRecord::Relation#to_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-to_sql):

```
User.where(query, *values).to_sql
```

Comment: My goal was to display SQL query string to the user, but not execute SQL. Your solution is the best, if SQL execution is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails (or at least ActiveRecord), I'd recommend using

```
ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_for_conditions(['(first_name = ?) AND (country = ?)', 'Bob', 'USA'])
```

Unless it's just for a regular `where` condition, in which case it will ActiveRecord will just do this for you in `User.where('(first_name = ?) AND (country = ?)', 'Bob', 'USA')`